# How do I query the Firebase authentication by phone number?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

In our React 16.13.0 application, we are using Firebase.  We link a user to a phone number like so

```
return firebase
  .auth()
  .currentUser.linkWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, recaptchaVerfier)
  .then(function (confirmationResult: any) {
    var code = window.prompt("Provide your SMS code");
    recaptchaVerfier.clear();
    return confirmationResult.confirm(code).then(() => {
      callback();
    });
  })
```

I was curious how would we then go back and query the Firebase authentication table for users that have a particular phone number, assuming that phone number is used as the identifier for the user, as seen in the portal Authentication view below

[image]

.  The purpose of querying is not for logging in, but rather for looking up various users.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot query the Authentication database with the Client SDKs but you can with the [Admin SDKs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin).

This means that you will need to implement this querying in your own server or in a Cloud Function.

You could for example write a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) that would return the user details for a specific user.

The code would look like:

```
exports.getUserByPhone = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

    try {

        const phoneNbr = data.phoneNbr;
        const userRecord = await admin.auth().getUserByPhoneNumber(phoneNbr);

        return userRecord;

    } catch (error) {
        // See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors

        // Also see here the error codes: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/errors
        // In particular, the auth/user-not-found code is returned if there is no existing user record corresponding to the provided identifier. 
    }

});
```

You would then call this Cloud Function from your front-end as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#call_the_function) in the doc, by passing the value of the desired `phoneNbr`.

Comment: @Dave Hello, did you have the time to look at the proposed solution? Thx